# Unable to run local version of testcafe via npm link

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Whenever I try to run a locally installed version of testcafe, I get the error `Cannot find module '../testcafe/lib/cli'`. Steps I've taken:

1. `git clone <testcafe>`, then cd to `testcafe`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm link`
4. cd to repo where my automated tests reside
5. `npm link testcafe`
6. Run `testcafe <browser>`

Results in

```sh
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:796
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/rcooper/testcafe/lib/cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:793:17)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Is there something else I need to do, to run a local version of this library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to build the TestCafe package. Run `npx gulp build` before the `npm link` command.

Comment: Great! Would this be the same for testcafe-hammerhead?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same `build` gulp task for testcafe-hammerhead.